# Webworkers: bad performance after page reload

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-worker

I am using a webworker to load an 3D object for three.js.
If i disable the browsercache the webworker has great performance, if i enable the browsercache and reload the page the webworker performs really bad.

Here are some debug outputs.

Performance browser cache disabled:

```
Page: starting...
Page: worker called at 0 miliseconds
Page: started loading file: ./Female_Idle_walk_idle_003.fbx.
    Loaded 0 of 1 files.
Worker: start at 0 miliseconds
Worker: model load start at 0 miliseconds
Worker: loading model 13 miliseconds
Worker: loading model 51 miliseconds
Worker: model loaded! 2440 miliseconds
Page: loading file: ./Female_Idle_walk_idle_003.fbx.
    Loaded 1 of 1 files.
Page: loading complete!
Page: model loaded!
Page: task finished in 5269 miliseconds
Page: worker replay at 6609 miliseconds
Page: worker task finished in 7547 miliseconds
```

Performance page reload with browser cache enabled:

```
Page: starting...
Page: worker called at 0 miliseconds
Page: started loading file: ./Female_Idle_walk_idle_003.fbx.
Loaded 0 of 1 files.
Page: loading file: ./Female_Idle_walk_idle_003.fbx.
Loaded 1 of 1 files.
Page: loading complete!
Page: model loaded!
Page: task finished in 2100 miliseconds
Worker: start at 2200 miliseconds
Worker: model load start at 2201 miliseconds
Worker: loading model 2208 miliseconds
Worker: loading model 2235 miliseconds
Worker: model loaded! 5907 miliseconds
Page: worker replay at 12989 miliseconds
Page: worker task finished in 13852 miliseconds
```

Does anybody have a clue why the webworker performs so much worse after a page reload?

worker.js:

```
importScripts('./three.js' + '?' + Math.random(),'./fflate.min.js' + '?' + Math.random(),'./FBXLoader.js' + '?' + Math.random());

addEventListener('message', e => {
  const startTime = e.data;
  console.log(`Worker: start at ${Number.parseInt(performance.now() - startTime)} miliseconds`);

  // male loader
  const maleLoader = new THREE.FBXLoader();

  console.log(`Worker: model load start at ${Number.parseInt(performance.now() - startTime)} miliseconds`);

  // male: async load
  let pMale = maleLoader.loadAsync('../_Male_idle_02.fbx', function (object) {
    console.log(`Worker: loading model ${Number.parseInt(performance.now() - startTime)} miliseconds`);

  });

  pMale.then(object => {
    console.log(`Worker: model loaded! ${Number.parseInt(performance.now() - startTime)} miliseconds`);

    postMessage(JSON.stringify(object));
  });
});
```

main.js - worker call

```
const worker = new Worker('./webworker/worker.js' + '?' + Math.random());

worker.addEventListener('message', e => {
    console.log(`Page: worker replay at ${Number.parseInt(performance.now() - startTime)} miliseconds`);

    // male loader
    const maleLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    maleLoader.parse(JSON.parse(e.data), function (object) {
        initModel(object);
        scene.add(object);
        console.log(`Page: worker finished in ${Number.parseInt(performance.now() - startTime)} miliseconds`);
    });
});
```

I tried to use the blob approach, but then my imported scripts threw XHR-errors. I also added random numbers to the query string of my scripts and the webworker.js. Both did not help at all.
I am clueless what is going on and need some advice. I also found nothing related to this topic.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: I recommend using the browser's performance profiler to get a view of the time spent in the various function calls. With a difference of 2s, it should be painfully obvious what function is taking so long.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @TheJim01. I am working on other stuff at the moment but i will try to figure out what is going on soon. I thought there is something commonly odd with webworkers that i am not aware of. The use of webworkers for loading models in compressed formats can be quite useful to improve the loading performance.